# Breadcrumb navigation. C#, Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, programming, visual-studio, navigation

I'm writing a desktop application. I would like to include a Breadcrumb navigation control, like the one in Windows explorer.

It looks like it is not included in the regular Toolbox in Visual studio 2013.

Does anybody know of a good alternative?!

[Breadcrumb navigation, so convenient !!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87596.png)

Answer (score 2):

[BCGSoft](http://www.bcgsoft.com/) has a control that's called CBCGPShellBreadcrumb.  Here's what it looks like.

[image]

I use many of their controls.  While their documentation is somewhat poor, they provide full source code.  Unfortunately, in your case, at the moment, they don't have a version of their library for Visual Studio **2013** .net languages.  They're pretty good at getting releases out, so it may be available soon.  Otherwise, if you set your platform toolset to **2012**, you should be able to use the control now.

If you can't wait, you can always craft your own version.  Using Spy++, you can see the types of composite controls that make up the Breadcrumb control.  It shouldn't be that difficult to craft one.

Comment: Great find. Thanks. I like their graphs too !! Definitely will look into it.